# first and last observations in sas

Tags: database, sas, data-management

I am trying to flag first and last observations based on baseline date (in my data set it is called baseline_doc) for all same groupings of client_id.

For example, I want my final dataset to look like this:

```
Client_id    Baseline_Date       First.baseline_doc    Last.baseline_doc 
---------    ------------------  ------------------    -----------------
1            April 1 2016        0                     0
1            April 20 2016       0                     1
1            January 1 2016      1                     0
2            January 1 2016      1                     0
2            January 20 2016     0                     1
3            February 20 2016    1                     1
```

Notice how within similar groupings of client_id first and last is flagged for the first instance of client_id and the last instance of that client_id AND THEN WITHIN each client_id grouping the first and last observation is flagged-the first date is flagged as 1 in first.baseline_doc and the last date (or most recent) is flagged as last.baseline_doc
This is the code I am using:

```
data FA_CA_DADOS_CLEAN_DELETED;
    set fa_ca_dados_clean2;
    by client_id baseline_doc;
    firstclient_id = first.client_id;
    lastclient_id = last.client_id;
    firstBaseline_doc = first.baseline_doc;
    lastBaseline_doc = last.baseline_doc;
run;
```

However, my code doesn't give me the output like I want. What is happening is that every client_id is getting tagged with a 1 for last.baseline_doc but there definitely are some that should be 0 b/c I have duplicate client_ids with different dates.

What am I doing wrong?

I copied this code directly from this resource:
https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat481/node/9

and it has the output I want so I'm not sure what is going on.

I proc sorted by client_id and baseline_doc before I ran the code above!

Can someone please help me?

Comment: You definitely do not get it. `first.something` means that this observation is the first one with a certain `something`. You are really confusing your colleagues if you use  `first.baseline_doc` for a completely different concept.

Comment: maybe you should firstly sort your input data by Client_id, Baseline_Date ?

Answer (score 1):

After reading in the data with

```
data myData;
    input @01 Client_id 1. 
        @03 Baseline_Doc date9. ;
    format Baseline_Doc yymmdd10.;
    datalines;
1  1Apr2016 0 0
1 20Apr2016 0 1
1  1Jan2016 1 0
2  1Jan2016 1 0
2 20Jan2016 0 1
3 20Feb2016 1 1
;
run;
```

This will do the job:

```
proc sql;
    select all.*
         , case baseline_Doc when baseline_min then 1 else 0 end as baseline_start
         , case baseline_Doc when baseline_max then 1 else 0 end as baseline_stop
    from myData all inner join 
    (   select Client_id
             , min(baseline_doc) as baseline_min
             , max(baseline_doc) as baseline_max
        from myData
        group by Client_id ) as min_max on all.Client_id = min_max.Client_id;
quit;
```

However, it could give unpleasant surprises, because according to the specifications of SQL, it does not have to preserve the order.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to flag the earliest and latest dates within each client_id. To do this, you need to look for first.client_id and last.client_id, not first.baseline_doc and last.baseline_doc. Think of first.x / last.x as equivalent to 'this is the first/last row with the current value of x'.

Try this instead:

```
data myData;
    input @01 Client_id 1. 
        @03 Baseline_Doc date9. ;
    format Baseline_Doc yymmdd10.;
    datalines;
1  1Apr2016 0 0
1 20Apr2016 0 1
1  1Jan2016 1 0
2  1Jan2016 1 0
2 20Jan2016 0 1
3 20Feb2016 1 1
;
run;

proc sort data = mydata;
  by client_id baseline_doc;
run;

data want;
  set mydata;
  by client_id;
  first_baseline_doc = first.client_id;
  last_baseline_doc  = last.client_id;
run;
```

Comment: with your answer you won't have the result data which want to see @chiccaboomberry

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be 100% sure the order is preserved, you can do this

*Sort the input in ascending order of baseline date, but remember the original observation number*;

```
data myInput;
   input @01 Client_id 1. 
         @03 Baseline_Doc date9. ;
   format Baseline_Doc yymmdd10.;
   obsNr = _N_;
   datalines;
1  1Apr2016 0 0
1 20Apr2016 0 1
1  1Jan2016 1 0
2  1Jan2016 1 0
2 20Jan2016 0 1
3 20Feb2016 1 1
;
run;
proc sort data = myInput out=myTemp;
  by client_id baseline_doc;
run;
```

*Mark the first and last baseline dates*;

```
data myTemp;
  set myTemp;
  by client_id baseline_doc;
  baseline_start = first.client_id;
  baseline_end = last.client_id;
run;
```

*Restore the original order and forget obsNr*;

```
proc sort data = myTemp out=myResult(drop=obsNr);
  by obsNr;
run;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
data myData;
   input @01 Client_id 1. 
         @03 Baseline_Doc date9. ;
   format Baseline_Doc yymmdd10.;
   datalines;
   1  1Apr2016 0 0
   1 20Apr2016 0 1
   1  1Jan2016 1 0
   2  1Jan2016 1 0
   2 20Jan2016 0 1
   3 20Feb2016 1 1
   ;
run;
proc sort data = mydata;
  by client_id baseline_doc;
run;

data want;
  set mydata baseline_doc;
  by client_id baseline_doc;
  if first.client_id then First.baseline_doc = 1;
  else First.baseline_doc = 0;
  if last.client_id then Last.baseline_doc = 1;
  else Last.baseline_doc = 0;
run;
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question (first. and last. variables are always dropped), it's confusing because of the use of first.baseline_doc, and apart from that it's almost an exact duplicate of my answer.